# Subir una imagen por URL HTML - JS

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas 
Estoy realizando un formulario en HTML con JS y tengo un campo para ingresar una imagen por URL 
mi idea es que se ingrese con un input type

{
input type="url" placeholder="Ingrese URL de la imagen">
}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como puedo mostrar la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Enmanuel , sería genial que añadieras el código en formato texto y no con imágenes. ¿Donde desea mostrar la imagen? en una etiqueta `img`?

Comment: Hola Enmanuel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general, y que leas [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, el código debería estar copiado en texto y no como imagen (el contenido de las imágenes no se indexa y no puede ser buscado o leído por algunos usuarios), sería ideal que crearas un [mcve] para poder ver el problema exacto, y además deberías incluir algo más de información (¿dónde quieres mostrar la imagen? ¿por qué no puedes mostrarla? ¿recibes algún error?)

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar la imagen solo debes capturar el valor ingresado en tu `input` una vez éste se haya cambiado, eso lo logras con el evento `change`, luego debes asignar ese valor al `src` de una etiqueta  `img`, algo así:

```js
$("#url").change(function(){
   var url = $(this).val();    
   $("#imagen").html('<img src="'+ url +'" alt="imagen">')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="url" placeholder="Ingrese URL de la imagen" id="url">
    <div id="imagen"></div>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !